# Python phase XML removing element by certain attributes and replace text within attributes

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following XML file:

```
<tv>
    <programme channel="BBC Red Button 1" start="20180422123000 +0000" stop="20180422125500 +0000">
        <title lang="en">Live Snooker: The World Championship: Day Two - 2018</title>
        <desc lang="en">Coverage of day two at the Crucible Theatre in Sheffield</desc>
        <category lang="en">Sport</category>
        <icon src="http://images.radiotimes.com/remote/static.radiotimes.com.edgesuite.net/pa/70/26/webANXsnookerlivebbc.jpg?quality=60&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=130&amp;height=100&amp;404=tv" />
    </programme>
    <programme channel="BBC Red Button 1" start="20180422125500 +0000" stop="20180422150000 +0000">
        <title lang="en">Live UEFA Women's Champions League</title>
        <desc lang="en">Manchester City v Lyon (Kick-off 1.00pm)</desc>
        <category lang="en">Sport</category>
        <icon src="http://images.radiotimes.com/assets/images/holding/tv.png?quality=60&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=130&amp;height=100&amp;404=tv" />
     </programme>
</tv>
```

First i'm trying to remove the element icon where the src equals

```
<icon src="http://images.radiotimes.com/assets/images/holding/tv.png?quality=60&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=130&amp;height=100&amp;404=tv" />
```

and then for the icons which are remaining i'm trying to replace `quality=60&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=130&amp;height=100` with `quality=100&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1200&amp;height=723`

So once the XML file is phased it will look like this:

```
<tv>
    <programme channel="BBC Red Button 1" start="20180422123000 +0000" stop="20180422125500 +0000">
        <title lang="en">Live Snooker: The World Championship: Day Two - 2018</title>
        <desc lang="en">Coverage of day two at the Crucible Theatre in Sheffield</desc>
        <category lang="en">Sport</category>
        <icon src="http://images.radiotimes.com/remote/static.radiotimes.com.edgesuite.net/pa/70/26/webANXsnookerlivebbc.jpg?quality=100&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1200&amp;height=723&amp;404=tv" />
    </programme>
    <programme channel="BBC Red Button 1" start="20180422125500 +0000" stop="20180422150000 +0000">
        <title lang="en">Live UEFA Women's Champions League</title>
        <desc lang="en">Manchester City v Lyon (Kick-off 1.00pm)</desc>
        <category lang="en">Sport</category>
     </programme>
</tv>
```

I first need to remove the icons which i don't want in the XML file before replacing the other values, so i don't end up changing the values of the icons which i want to remove, so far i have tried the following to remove the icons but i have not had any success in doing so:

```
#!/bin/sh

from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

t = ElementTree()
t.parse('/volume1/TVMosaic/Freeview-WG++/guide.xml')
programmeList = t.findall('tv/programme/icon')
for programmeEl in programmeList:
    if programmeEl.attrib['src'] in ('http://images.radiotimes.com/assets/images/holding/tv.png?quality=60&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=130&amp;height=100&amp;404=tv') and \
            programmeEl.attrib['src'] == programmeEl.text:
        del programmeEl.attrib['src']
t.write('/volume1/TVMosaic/Freeview-WG++/PhasedGuide.xml')
```

Would someone be able to help me with removing icons which have that src which i mentioned and then replacing the values in the rest of the icons with the values which i mentioned earlier.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the string that you're looking for is *XML **escaped*** (note the "**&*amp;***"s), while when parsing the file, the strings are unescaped (**&*amp;*** converted to ***&*** - and some more others). For more details check [[Python.Wiki]: Escaping XML](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape, unescape


INPUT_FILE_NAME = "guide.xml"
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "PhasedGuide.xml"
SRC_ATTR_TEXT = "http://images.radiotimes.com/assets/images/holding/tv.png?quality=60&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=130&amp;height=100&amp;404=tv"
SRC_ATTR_REPLACE_TEXT = "quality=60&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=130&amp;height=100"
SRC_ATTR_REPLACE_WITH_TEXT = "quality=100&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1200&amp;height=723"


def main():
    tree = ET.parse(INPUT_FILE_NAME)
    tv_node = tree.getroot()
    for programme_node in tv_node.findall("programme"):
        icon_node = programme_node.find("icon")
        if icon_node is not None:
            print(icon_node.get("src", ""))
            src_attr = escape(icon_node.get("src", ""))
            if src_attr == SRC_ATTR_TEXT:
                programme_node.remove(icon_node)
            elif src_attr:
                icon_node.set("src", unescape(src_attr.replace(SRC_ATTR_REPLACE_TEXT, SRC_ATTR_REPLACE_WITH_TEXT)))
    tree.write(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- The algorithm loads and parses the file, and gets the root node (*tv*)
- Iterates through all its *programme* children
- For each, tries to find an *icon* child, if found get its *src* attribute (the value is **escaped**)
- Then, depending on the attribute (escaped) value, it performs the required operation

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049967927>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q049967927>type PhasedGuide.xml
> <tv>
>     <programme channel="BBC Red Button 1" start="20180422123000 +0000" stop="20180422125500 +0000">
>         <title lang="en">Live Snooker: The World Championship: Day Two - 2018</title>
>         <desc lang="en">Coverage of day two at the Crucible Theatre in Sheffield</desc>
>         <category lang="en">Sport</category>
>         <icon src="http://images.radiotimes.com/remote/static.radiotimes.com.edgesuite.net/pa/70/26/webANXsnookerlivebbc.jpg?quality=100&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1200&amp;height=723&amp;404=tv" />
>     </programme>
>     <programme channel="BBC Red Button 1" start="20180422125500 +0000" stop="20180422150000 +0000">
>         <title lang="en">Live UEFA Women's Champions League</title>
>         <desc lang="en">Manchester City v Lyon (Kick-off 1.00pm)</desc>
>         <category lang="en">Sport</category>
>         </programme>
> </tv>
> ```

Comment: Did this answer your question??